# R - Search for a text in a data frame and assign a count to a separate column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which lists MS Office programs and the data on which they crashed on various computers around our home:

```
Services-Impacted  Date
MS Word            2013-03-01
MS Excel           2013-03-03
MS Powerpoint      2014-01-01
Excel,ppt,word     2014-05-04
MS Word            2015-03-01
MS Excel           2015-03-03
MS Powerpoint      2015-01-01
```

I'm looking to search the dataframe by Row and if say "MS Excel" or "excel" can be found to assign the value 1 to a new column called say MS Word and 0 if not found. So i would like a end result like this:

```
Services-Impacted  Date        MS Word MS Excel MS Powerpoint
MS Word            2013-03-01  1       0        0
MS Excel           2013-03-03  0       1        1
MS Powerpoint      2014-01-01  0       0        1
Excel,ppt,word     2014-05-04  1       1        1
MS Word            2015-03-01  1       0        0
MS Excel           2015-03-03  0       1        1
MS Powerpoint      2015-01-01  0       0        0
```

I've looked a bunch of different methods:

```
"MS Word" %in% Office$Services-Impacted[1]
TRUE

count the number of rows
i <-nrow(Office)
i

loop for the number of rows
for(i in 1:i)
    {
      # diff the time and print it out
      "MS Word " %in% Office$Services-Impacted[i]

    }
```

The first line Works well but can't figure how to iterate though the entire data frame as the lopping with [i] does not return a list of TRUE or FALSE
Also can't figure out how to use wildcard searches i'd have to hard code each search.

I've also researched some options like grep and filter but these only filter a table rather than give me a mechanism to populate the product columns with 1 or 0.

Thanks in advance for any replies
Jonathan

Comment: I can't help but notice, you've used `i in 1:i` as part of your for loop..

Comment: Are you sure that the values in the expected output are correct?  In the second row, how do you get 1 for MS Power point?

Comment: Well spotted i had a typo in the original dataframe text. I've since correct that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mtabulate` from `qdapTools` after splitting the 'Services-Impacted' column

```
library(qdapTools)
d1 <- mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df1[,'Services-Impacted']), ','))
i1 <- grep("(?i)(e)xcel", names(d1))
i2 <- grep("Power|ppt$", names(d1))
cbind(df1, +(data.frame(MSWord = d1[,5], MSExcel = rowSums(d1[i1]), 
                MSPowerpoint = rowSums(d1[i2]))!=0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, this looks good. My rep is too low to upvote your answer. Regards